# Filling complex figures with color

Tags: color, diagrams

I wonder if there is any method available in LaTeX to fill complex figures. There are few methods for filling figures: **even-odd rule algorithm**, **winding number algorithm**. According to these algorithms, the figure can be filled for particular regions.

For instance:

[image]

Please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for a reference.

Suppose we have some complex figure, e.g. self-crossing polygon, is that possible to fill it with some of above mentioned algorithms?

Comment: `even odd rule` is already implemented in TikZ. See the manual page 34 and 163.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ has a key called `even odd rule` which I assume use the first of those. An example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[even odd rule] (0,0) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (3,1.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example, from the manual:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[fill=green,even odd rule]
    (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (0.5,0.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \draw[->] (0.5,0.5) -- +(0,1) [above] node{crossings: $1+1 = 2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Many thanks! That's what I've looked for!